# System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert - how to disable in a .NET Core console app?

Tags: c#, .net-core, assert

Consider the following simple program:

```
using System;

namespace DebugAssertTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(6 == 7, "Bang!");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

When compiled as a .NET Framework console app and executed, the Assert triggers and the Assert UI dialog box is displayed.  (Assert failed.  Abort, Retry, Ignore etc)
By adding an App.Config file containing the following, the Assert UI is disabled and "Hello World!" is displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <assert assertuienabled="false" />
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

When the same code is compiled as a .NET Core console app and executed, the Assert triggers and the app terminates.  Instead of a UI dialog box, the console displays this:

```
Process terminated. Assertion failed.
Bang!
   at DebugAssertTesting.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Development\DebugAssert\DebugAssert\Program.cs:line 9

C:\Development\DebugAssert\DebugAssert\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\DebugAssert.exe (process 38028) exited with code -2146232797.
```

Is there a way to disable the Assert within a .NET Core console app like there is in a .NET Framework app?
Adding an App.Config file with the content above does not affect the behaviour.  (VS2019 copies the file to the output folder, renaming it as expected but the app still terminates on the Assert.)

Can the Assert behaviour be controlled by settings within the app's runtimeconfig.json file?  If so, does anyone know the correct syntax?
I've tried a few so far without any luck.  I've searched for the equivalent of assertuienabled and drawn a blank.
The Microsoft documentation for Debug.Assert clearly shows that it is supported in all .NET Core variants, but only mentions controlling via App.Config.

Comment: The real way to do this is to _not_ supply the DEBUG constant, ie Build and Run in Release mode. Otherwise, just remove that Assert() line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the `DEBUG` constant from `DefineConstants` property in `csproj` file, change this

```
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
```

to just

```
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
```

Or uncheck the checkbox on `Build` tab of project properties

[image]

Another option is remove the [`DefaultTraceListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener?view=netcore-3.1) from [`Trace.Listeners`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace.listeners?view=netcore-3.1) collection

```cs
Trace.Listeners.RemoveAt(0);

Debug.Assert(6 == 7, "Bang!");
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

It'll print you `Hello World!` text.

You can also add new listener and set `AssertUiEnabled` or `LogFileName` properties in code (in the similar way with `app.config` in .NET Framework).

Last option is to override [`Fail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.fail?view=netcore-3.1) method to customize the `Assert` behavior, have a look at [Customizing Assert behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/assertions-in-managed-code?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Customizing_Assert_behavior) article for details

Comment: Removing the trace listener does what I want.  Thanks!